# PhotoShop: How to delete a selection after you're done with it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I use the pent tool to make a shape, then right click make a selection, I fill in the selection with the colour I want.  Great perfect no problem.

Now say if I want to go to the stamp tool and work on a different area of the picture, the previous selection from the pen tool still exists, and I can't use the stamp tool.  I cant seem to figure out how to get rid of the previous selection.

Comment: Hello Jesse and welcome to GD! Thanks for the contribution and let us know if you have any questions as to how the site works

Comment: `cmd` + `D` on OS X or `Ctrl` + `D` on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just click inside the selection area with one of the selection tools. Alternatively, try `Select > Deselect`.

Comment: thanks this program is quite finicky but awesome

Comment: @JesseMacDougall If Alex's answer solved this for you then please mark it the correct answer by hitting the checkbox next to it. Thanks and welcome to the community.

Answer (score -2):

if there is any selections still Exist you can do without Deselect. Just Inverse the Selection using CMD+D in Mac And CTRL+D In Windows
(or)
select > deselect